# Why do I get a blank app when I refresh the url with the 'id' in the end in Emberjs?

Tags: javascript, url, ember.js

I have nested routes like this,

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('twod', function() {
        this.resource('twoduser', {
            path : '/:user_id'
        });
    });
    this.resource('threed');

});
```

And I have a list generated by `{{link-to}}` and whenever I click on on any one of them, it shows me the template for 'twoduser', that's what I intended to do, okay and it updates the url like this,

```
http://ember.local/#/twod/2
```

which was before,

```
http://ankur.local/#/twod
```

Whenever I refresh the url, the page goes blank and I get this on console,

```
Error while loading route:
TypeError: App.Twod.findBy is not a function
```

Here's the route method for the twoduser:

```
App.TwoduserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return App.Twod.findBy('id', params.user_id);
    }
});
```

One more thing to note is I am fetching data using Ajax,

```
App.Twod.reopenClass({
    findAll : function() {
        return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            $.getJSON("http://pioneerdev.us/users/index", function(data) {
                var result = data.users.map(function(row) {
                    return App.Twod.create(row);
                });
                resolve(result);
            }).fail(reject);
        });
    }
});
```

What I can do to solve that issue?

Comment: There is no `findBy()` method on `DS.Model` (assuming you're using ember-data 0.13), try `find(params.user_id)`.

Comment: I am not using Ember-Data, I am actually using Ajax calls to fetch data. You can see my latest edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the `findBy` function if you want to use it.  The reason that it works when you click in, but not when you reload, is that in your `link-to` it implicitly assumes that the current object is the `model` for the new route, and it is just passed directly to the controller, bypassing the `model` hook.  When you hit reload the `model` hook is executed, but fails because you're trying to call a method that does not exist.

If you need a `findBy` function you should create it in your model, next to your `findAll` method.

```
App.Twod.reopenClass({
    findAll : function() {
        // your find all function here
    },
    findBy : function(id){
        // your code to find by id here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. I was refreshing inside of a nested resources e.g. `/users/1/photos/2` but I did not have an api endpoint such as `/api/photos/1` to request a single photo object. I added an endpoint and it fixed itself. Before fixing, I was trying to lean on the index api endpoint or sideloading in `/api/users/` but as Jeremy explained, when you refresh, it takes the deepest route as the model and looks up based on that first.

Hope this helps someone!